# Open an embedded msg attachment

Tags: c, outlook, mapi

I have a Microsoft Outlook msg file which has an embedded msg file. I can get the attachment, save it as a file, but I cannot access it as a msg object.

I am using C, I cannot use C++ or C# or any other language.

To get the size of the attachment, I read the `PR_ATTACH_SIZE` property of the attachment, but the size I get is smaller than the size of the file when I save the attachment.

I tried to use `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ`, `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` and `MAPIOBJECT` in order to get the attached embedded msg, but all these functions fail.

How do I get the attached msg as a proper msg?

Answer (score 0):

Call `IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ, IID_IMessage, ...)` to open an embedded message attachment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not helpful.
I can use ONLY the interfaces provided by the Outlook typelib. Basically I have to use MailItem, Attachments and Attachment. The problem is that when the attachment is embedded message then I tried to use both schemas "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102" (for PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN) and "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3701000D" (for PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ) and in both cases I get interface not supported.

I also tried to call MAPIOBJECT from Attachment interface, but it didn't work. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: If you are not using MAPI, OOM won't let you do that. The best you can do is save the attachment as an MSG file using `Attachment.SaveAsFile`, then open it using `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`. If using Redemption (I am its author) is an option, it exposes `EmbeddedMsg` property on the `RDOAttachment` object.

Comment: I did save the msg attachment, and it is saved fine. I will try to open it. Unfortunately I cannot use Redemption, all I can use is only C (no C++ or any other language)

Comment: Have you tried to use Namespace.OpenSharedItem?

Comment: I just tried and is not working. The return value (HRESULT) when I read the saved msg file is 0x80020009

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: I cannot show the code, sorry for that. I can only use the interfaces Outlook offers in the typelib

Comment: It is really impossible to tell what is wrong with your code if you do not even show what your code is.